# how to set the right canvas in an firemonkey application?

Tags: firemonkey

I have 2d scene editor based on firemonkey. The user can select/move various complex 2d objects on his iPad.  My problem, the objects are drawn on the scrollbar also.

The visual structure is simple. The form contains a tabcontrol. The tabcontrol's editor tab has two scrollbar (right, bottom). On the tab client area there is a TLayout type component (aligned alClient). The 2d objects parents are the layout component. The 2d object parent type is TShape.

I assume the application draw on the form directly instead of drawing on the editor tab. How to set the correct drawing canvas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
Layout.ClipChildren := True;
```